# asp:menu with image has padding above

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a menu bar in the site master in a table. For some reason I cant figure out there is always padding above it.

This is the css:

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.menu ul li 
{
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a
{ 
    padding: 4px 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #2c4257;
}

div.menu a ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #25394B;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #25394B;
    color: #ef7c31;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #25394B;
    color: #ef7c31;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:left
}
```

and this is in the site master

```
 <table style="background-color: #2E4459">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <asp:Menu ID="SettingsMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="True" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu">
             <DynamicSelectedStyle ForeColor="#ef7c31" />
                 <Items>
                     <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="Images/settings.png">
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/CRMSettings/Area.aspx" Text="Area" />
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/CRMSettings/Post.aspx" Text="Post" />
```

I don't know how to fix it there is around 30 px.

[image]

Its also happening with out the image, if I just put text.

[image] This is the setting.png

Comment: which browser you testing on? and also mention the version please..

Comment: chrome and version 4.5 for asp

Comment: Can you please upload your settings.png. So I can test it.What you need to posissition your image to x=0, and y=0.Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

try that

Comment: what happens when you use firebug inspect element feature? hover over the padding and tell me where it's coming from. Are you sure it's coming from the menu and not bottom padding from the div above it? Firebug should tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: yes it's comming from the menu, there is nothing above it. When I put text in the table there is no padding, only with the menu

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Try this. Add this to your `CSS`

```
html,body
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: If this is not what you needed,please update your post with an image. Then it will be easy for us to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

what I figured-out was there is a `padding` **padding: 4px 20px;** value for `div.menu ul li a` changing that will help you. change it to **div.menu ul li ul li a**

```
div.menu ul li ul li a
{ 
    padding: 4px 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #2c4257;
}
```